# convert to anchor only if not an html

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's assume, I have the following text:

```
This is a sample url : http://example.com.
These are some images:
<img src="http://example.com/sample1.png" class="sample-image" />
<img src="http://example.com/sample2.png" class="sample-image" />
Another url http://example2.com
```

Here is regex code that I am using to parse the above text:

```
const urls = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;-]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
    const emails = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim;

    return function(text) {
        if(text.match(urls)) {
            text = text.replace(urls, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>")
        }
        if(text.match(emails)) {
            text = text.replace(emails, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>")
        }

        return text
    }
```

The above code does this to my text:

```
This is a sample url : <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>.
These are some images:
<img src="<a href=" class="sample-image">"http://example.com/sample1.png">"
<img src="<a href=" class="sample-image">"http://example.com/sample2.png">"
Another url <a href="http://example2.com">http://example2.com</a>
```

And I desire the following result:

```
This is a sample url : <a href="http://example.com">http://example.com</a>.
These are some images:
<img src="http://example.com/sample1.png" class="sample-image" /> <!-- Do not change -->
<img src="http://example.com/sample2.png" class="sample-image" /> <!-- Do not change -->
Another url <a href="http://example2.com">http://example2.com</a>
```

How can I achieve the above result?

Comment: Add to page, and loop trough textContents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to avoid using regex for parsing HTML.

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

[Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

---

Instead, generate a temporary DOM element with the content and fetch all text nodes to update the content. Where apply replace the method with regex on the text node contents.

```js
var html = 'This is a sample url : http://example.com These are some images:<img src="http://example.com/sample1.png" class="sample-image" /><img src="http://example.com/sample2.png" class="sample-image" />Another url http://example2.com';

// regex for replacing content
const urls = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;-]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
const emails = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim;

// for replacing the content
function update(text) {
  return text.replace(urls, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>").replace(emails, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>");
}

// create a DOM element
var temp = document.createElement('div');
// set the string as your content
temp.innerHTML = html;

console.log(
  // get all child nodes and convert into array
  // for older browser use `[].slice.call()`
  Array.from(temp.childNodes)
  // iterate over the elements to generate the content array
  .map(function(n) {
    // if node is text then update the content and return it
    if (n.nodeType == 3)
      return update(n.textContent);
    // otehrwise return the html content
    else
      return n.outerHTML;
    // join them 
  }).join('')
)
```

---

**UPDATE :** In case you need to keep the escaped HTML then you need to add an additional method which generates corresponding escaped HTML of a text node.

```js
var html = 'This is a sample url : http://example.com These are some images:<img src="http://example.com/sample1.png" class="sample-image" /><img src="http://example.com/sample2.png" class="sample-image" />Another url http://example2.com  hi &lt;a href="#"&gt;Sam&lt;/a&gt;';

// regex for replacing content
const urls = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;-]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
const emails = /(\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gim;

// for replacing the content
function update(text) {
  return text.replace(urls, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>").replace(emails, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>");
}

// function for generating escaped html content for text node
function getEncodedText(node) {
    // temporary element  
    var temp = document.createElement('div');
    // append the text node
    temp.appendChild(node);
    // get the escaped html content
    return temp.innerHTML
  }
  // create a DOM element
var temp = document.createElement('div');
// set the string as your content
temp.innerHTML = html;

console.log(
  // get all child nodes and convert into array
  // for older browser use `[].slice.call()`
  Array.from(temp.childNodes)
  // iterate over the elements to generate the content array
  .map(function(n) {
    // if node is text then update the escaped html content and return it
    if (n.nodeType == 3)
      return update(getEncodedText(n));
    // otehrwise return the html content
    else
      return n.outerHTML;
    // join them 
  }).join('')
)
```

Comment: @PranavCBalan The above code unscapes escaped html, for example, `hi &lt;a href="#"&gt;Sam&lt;/a&gt;` to `hi <a href="#">Sam</a>`. How to not unscape escaped html in above code

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thank you

Comment: @SamarRizvi :  glad to help  :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
str='This is a sample url : http://example.com.\nThese are some images:\n<img src="http://example.com/sample1.png" class="sample-image" />\n<img src="http://example.com/sample2.png" class="sample-image" />\nAnother url http://example2.com';

str= str.replace(/[^"](https?:\/\/[^"\s]+)/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
console.log(str);
```

**Output:**

```
This is a sample url :<a href="http://example.com.">http://example.com.</a>
These are some images:
<img src="http://example.com/sample1.png" class="sample-image" />
<img src="http://example.com/sample2.png" class="sample-image" />
Another url<a href="http://example2.com">http://example2.com</a>
```